# Simulate Couch to 5K at Home

Tags: running, jogging, walking, couchto5k

I wish to start Couch to 5k soon.

Due to logistics, family, etc, I am confined to exercise in my apartment (at least till it warms up again)

How to do couch to 5k standing in one place.

I know how to jog in place, but how to walk and run in place? There must be a way.

[Couch to 5K](http://www.c25k.com/c25k_metric.html)

Comment: Are you stuck in a very cold country?

Comment: @jjosaur There are other issues

Comment: Can you give us some more detail about the problems you have with running outside?

Comment: @JJosaur Live in unsafe neighborhood. Plus I have work-family  issues that don't provide extra time to travel to running club. Hope to get this resolved by Spring next year. Hence the indoor starter training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much space do you have? Is there a clear space of at least 5 foot by 10 foot, that you could use? It doesn't even need to be entirely clear, just enough that you can move without constantly tripping. Hallways can serve the purpose if you don't have room in your apartment. This is what I do in inclement weather, or when I don't feel like dressing up to work out (obviously less feasible for the hallway method).

Alternately, if you feel that you must practice in place, walking in place is just a matter of picking up your feet alternately. Unlike running or jogging, you always have one foot on the ground. As with other forms of stationary exercise, I'd advise lifting your knees a bit more to compensate for not having the extra effort of actually moving.

As for differentiating running and jogging... honestly, that's largely a matter of semantics. For the purpose of stationary exercise, they're basically the same thing, just a matter of how intensely you're moving.

Either way, you will likely be using the time method rather than the distance method, really not an issue.

Comment: Hello Sean, this is very encouraging. I can work on getting 5 x 10 space in the apartment. Very encouraging!

Comment: {nods} You'll be doing very tight corners, but it's doable.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your goals. If you want to run a 5k, there are a lot of variables to learn and practice: cadence, pacing, joint fatigue, and many more that you just won't experience by doing jogging on the spot.

And there are logistical/mathematical issues with measuring 5 kilometers jogged on the spot.

You really need to look at how much you value your health and fitness. A gym membership can be affordable in most countries and even supplemented by local authority in some too (USA has the YMCA, UK has council gyms, etc).

Comment: There are other factors that are making me stay indoors for now (beyond the forums).

Answer (score 0):

Rhonda, you can alternate between marching in place and jogging in place. You can work similar muscles to those you would work running outside by alternating days of running in place with resistance exercises and high intensity interval trainings that include other types of cardio such as jumping jacks or high knees. This should round out your program nicely. Look for free videos on YouTube to get ideas. Leslie Sansone has some walk at home videos that include jogging intervals. I use those sometimes when I am stuck inside due to rain or a sick toddler. You can also find her on YouTube.

Comment: Welcome to Fitness Stack Exchange. Please note that discussion of other answers should only be made as comments, not as additional answers. (Sufficient [reputation](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) is required before comments can be made, however.) - [From Review](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/21307)